# Opaque SOCKS proxying?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, webserver, socks-proxy

There's this website I'm using which allows access based on your IP address, and my university's servers have access. Problem is, when I browse from one of the servers directly, I'm allowed access, but if I use a SOCKS proxy (with an SSH tunnel) to browse from a PC of mine, I don't get recognized. I suspect the SOCKS proxy is somehow reporting the PC's IP (maybe using the X-FORWARDED-FOR or Via headers?). How can I get my proxying done more opaquely?

I'll mention that if I just SSH-tunnel the connection to the website's HTTP port, I can connect just fine, so it's not some other issue in my setup.

I was thinking maybe something like SSH-tunneling to remotely-stated SOCKS host might work - but maybe there's something simpler/better.

**Notes**:

1. I control the client machine, but only have a user account on the server. Assume I can't do anything which will attract too much attention from the sysadmins. It's a big system, though, with hundreds logged in at any given time.
2. I'm interested in either Windows and Linux solutions, preferable both.

Answer (score 3):

Only HTTP proxy may have the header X-FORWARDED-FOR or VIA. All socks proxies are highly anonymous (Opaque). They won't report your real IP address to the website. Maybe the socks proxy server itself doesn't have the access to the website.

FYI, Socks Proxy VS HTTP Proxy: 
http://www.multiip.net/socks-proxy-http-proxy/

Comment: Perhaps it's not about the headers, and there's some other way the server determines my connection is proxied. However, the SOCKS server itself (which runs on my machine naturally) does have access to the website. Also, what you wrote is not an answer to my question...

Comment: As a suggestion I wouldn't just post a link but rather summarize the things found therein.

Comment: @einpoklum Did you try clearing your cache/cookies? I already have been denied access to IP-limited sites (scientific literature), and even after enabling the VPN of my university, the denial continued because there was a session cookie, and once you have an open session, you either have access or not. Same thing the other way around: if you have a valid session then you can switch to a "invalid" IP for the rest of the session (not sure when it expires, probably between 15 min and 2 hours) and generally it works. At least that's my experience with several publishers.

Comment: @Ale: Good point, I think I did, but I'll double-check when this next comes up for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your browser is Firefox, then you can spoof your IP address via addons.
This might (or might not) be enough to throw off the access control.

Here are two addons that generate false IP addresses and might be useful (but which I never had any reason to try) :

[ipFlood](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ipflood/)
[IPFuck](http://ipfuck.paulds.fr/)

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Then use ipFlood. There is supposed to be in the prefs the possibility for a non-random IP.

Answer (score 0):

Better setup a VPN. The socks5 protocol doesnt't tunnel your whole traffic correctly. If you want a secure & stable solution setup a vpn on your server and use one of these following vpn clients:

OpenVPn
Vicsority

Comment: It's not my server... I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: Which Client do you use for the Socks Proxy?

Comment: I tried PuTTY and BitVise Tunnelier.

Comment: Try Proxifier. It supports Socks4/5 protocol

Comment: And the two I mentioned? They're also SOCKS. Does it have some specific advantage?

Comment: I collected positive experience with proxifier. i never tested a socks proxy with putty or tunnelier.

Comment: Well, installing that it seems it does not support tunneling over SSH.